# jQuery Datatables - how to programatically sort by a column

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

So I have a datatable:

```
$(tables[i]).DataTable({
    paging: false,
    searching: false,
    info: false,
    ordering: true,
    autoWidth: false,
    columns: [ ... column stuff here ... 
        {name: "Name"},
        {name: "Account"},
        {name: "Number"}
    ]
});
```

later in code, I watch for a click event on a button so that I can grab some data from the table and then sort by a column

```
var columnName = $('.mySelectBox').val();
var columnNumber = 0;

if(columnName === "Account")
    columnNumber = 1;

var table = $(tables[i]).DataTable();
```

I would like to now sort by either column 0 or column one on this button click. 
But not on any other column.

```
//this doesn't work for me
table.sort( [ [columnNumber, 'desc'] ] );
```

Comment: Try `fnSort` instead of `sort`? Or add `order: [[columnNumber, 'desc' ]]` to `$(tables[i]).DataTable({ ... });` ?

Comment: `aaSorting: [[ columnNumber, "desc" ]]` or if you want to use fnsort do your dataTable initialization in a variable and fnsort on that variable

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc When I try fnSort it tells me it's not a function.

Comment: do you do it like this? `myTable.fnSort( [ [columnNumber,'desc'] ] );`

Comment: Yes, in exactly that manner.

Comment: I haven't tried aaSorting as I don't need sorting on initialization, but a programatic call to sort.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I use `.order()` instead of `.sort()`. Example:

`$('#dataTables-example').DataTable().order([0, 'desc']).draw();`

where `0` is the id of the column.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that using **order** method of the table. Youcan adopt the following technique.

We need to do two things here.

- Get current column index
- Apply ascending or descending action on particular column on click of a icon

Here let us assume we have a button or link to which **click** to bind.

```
$(".arrow-sort-ascending").bind("click", {
 // Sorting should happen here
}
```

#### Getting column index

I use generic way to get column name. If you are using Jquery, we can fetch the column index using this.

```
myColumn = $(parent).prevAll().length
```

where **parent** should be the **th** of particular column.

#### Applying ascending or descending sort

```
 // ascending
 myTable.order([myColumn, "asc"]).draw()
```

So if we put the code in a single section, it looks like this.

```
table = myTable // This is datatable you initialized

$(".arrow-sort-ascending").bind("click", {table: table}, function(event){
    parent = $(event.target).parent()
    myIndex = $(parent).prevAll().length;
    table.order([myIndex, "asc"]).draw()
}
```

So whenever we click the arrow-up icon, it sorts the clicked column.