# Custom sort function not called onLoad of Jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables-1.10

I have added a custom sort functionality in datatable. It works fine when the table header is clicked. However, On pageLoad I want the table to be sorted by that column using the same logic as provided in the custom sort function.
It does not seem to do so.
Here is my code snippet

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#stripedTableAcp").DataTable({
    "columnDefs": [
      { 
        "type": "acp_name",
        "targets": 3
      } 
    ],
    "order": [[ 3, "asc" ]],
    "pageLength": 100,
    "lengthMenu": [100, 500, 1000, 2000, 5000]
  });

  $.fn.dataTableExt.oSort["acp_name-desc"] = function (x, y)
  {
    console.log("1");
    x = jQuery(x).text();
    y = jQuery(y).text();

    temp = x.split("-");
    xPart1 = temp[0];
    xPart2 = parseInt(temp[1]);

    temp = y.split("-");
    yPart1 = temp[0];
    yPart2 = parseInt(temp[1]);

    if(xPart1 > yPart1)
    {
      return -1;
    }

    if(xPart2 > yPart2)
    {
      return -1;
    }

    return 1;
  };

  $.fn.dataTableExt.oSort["acp_name-asc"] = function (x, y)
  {
    console.log("2");
    x = jQuery(x).text();
    y = jQuery(y).text();

    temp = x.split("-");
    xPart1 = temp[0];
    xPart2 = parseInt(temp[1]);

    temp = y.split("-");
    yPart1 = temp[0];
    yPart2 = parseInt(temp[1]);

    if(xPart1 > yPart1)
    {
      return 1;
    }

    if(xPart2 > yPart2)
    {
      return 1;
    }

    return -1;
  }
});
```

Please note that the console.log added to the function is fired when the table header is clicked but not upon page load

datatable version is 1.10.19 as provided by the CDN

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with initializing the datatable before initializing the custom plugins. Once the plugin code was moved before declaring the datatable, the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared them only. Call [order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31459241/jquery-datatables-how-to-programatically-sort-by-a-column) in the last line of document.ready().

Comment: Thanks @m4gic ! but it is a default functionality of datatable to sort the table contents as per the order parameter provided during initialization. I dont get it why an explicit invocation might be required.